# Can variadic functors in C++ support named fields?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm implementing a variadic functor generic called "`Signal<args>`" which manages an internal queue of functors of matching function signature types. On calling  `Signal<args>::operator()` every functor in the queue is executed with the same input args. The idea is that it is a pure C++11 object type which recreates some of the same design behaviors as Qt's Signal/Slot construct, but statically compiled with minimal dependencies. I have everything working, but I'd like to improve the readability of this generic.

Syntax I have:

```
Signal<int, double> signal;
signal.add(BLOCK, [](int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber) {
    std::cout << EmployeeNames[EmployeeID]
              << " has favorite number of "
              << FavoriteNumber << std::endl;
});
signal.add(BLOCK, [](int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber) {
    if (EmployeeID > FavoriteNumber) {
        std::cout << EmployeeNames[EmployeeID]
                  << " has ID bigger than favorite number.\n";
    }
});
signal(5, 3.1415); //execute both functors with args = (5, 3.1415)
```

What I would like to have:

```
Signal<int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber> signal;
signal.add(BLOCK, [](int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber) {
    std::cout << EmployeeNames[EmployeeID]
              << " has favorite number of "
              << FavoriteNumber << std::endl;
});
signal.add(BLOCK, [](int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber) {
    if (EmployeeID > FavoriteNumber) {
        std::cout << EmployeeNames[EmployeeID]
                  << " has ID bigger than favorite number.\n";
    }
});
signal(5, 3.1415); //execute both functors with args = (5, 3.1415)
```

The only difference is that I would like the declaration of the templated signal type to specify a name for the parameter for readability sake. Ideally I would like these names to be mandatory and fail compilation if unspecified.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to have different parameters sharing the same data type? If not, you could use a simple trait type.

Comment: What's the difference between the two pieces of code? All I see is that the `Signal<int, double>` becomes `Signal<int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber>`. Is there any other difference you need?

Comment: Argument name is not a part of function signature, so I do not think you can achieve that

Comment: if you want this for readability, you could make type aliases like `typedef int EmployeeIDType` and use them in your signal (ie `Signal<EmployeeIDType, FavoriteNumberType>`)

Comment: @Justin I may have given a poor example, but if it was Signal<int,int,int> and those were intended to be an input fd, output fd, and user ID then you may have no clue which order those arguments are intended to be supplied in your input functor or at invocation of Signal<Args>::operator()

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that function types allow names for their parameters, letting you write:

```
Signal<void(int EmployeeID, double FavoriteNumber)> mySignal;
```

The name isn't mandatory, but it is allowed.

To do this, have a partial specialization for `Signal`:

```
template <typename>
class Signal;

template <typename... Args>
class Signal<void(Args...)> {
    // Old implementation of Signal<...>
};
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid template specialization but that's seeming the best option

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to use tag types, like

```
struct EmployeeID_T {};
struct FavoriteNumber_T {};
```

and bind the argument type to the name, like

```
using EmployeeID = SignalArg<EmployeeID_T, int>;
using FavoriteNumber = SignalArg<FavoriteNumber_T, double>
```

so you get

```
Signal<EmployeeID, FavoriteNumber> mySignal;
signal.add(BLOCK, [](EmployeeID eid, FavoriteNumber fn) {
    std::cout << EmployeeNames[eid]
              << " has favorite number of "
              << fn << std::endl;
});
signal.add(BLOCK, [](EmployeeID eid, FavoriteNumber fn) {
    if (eid > fn) {
        std::cout << EmployeeNames[eid]
                  << " has ID bigger than favorite number.\n";
    }
});
mySignal(5, 3.1415); //execute both functors with args = (5, 3.1415)
```

You need a `SignalArg` template with appropriate constructors and conversion operators, but since I haven't written it out, some coercion may be required.

The tag types prevent implicit conversion between different arguments with the same underlying type, which just using a typedef would allow.

You can also get something like named parameters by making the SignalArg converting constructor explicit, so the call would instead look something like

```
mySignal(EmployeeID{5}, FavoriteNumber{3.1415});
```

Comment: The names could even be declared on the spot: `Signal<SignalArg<struct EmployeeId, int>, SignalArg<struct FavoriteNumber, double>> mySignal;`

Comment: true, but then the lamba parameter lists are uglier

Comment: I was previously considering typedefs. Tag types works better in that it forces type-safety, but it faults on the same problem that I ruled out typedefs: it requires optional effort on the driver code, and my devs are lazy. They'll inline magic-numbers and hard-coded filepaths everywhere just to spare the hassle of defining the occasional member variable. If I leave them the option to not create a tag type or typedef, they simply won't.

Comment: @corruptedsyntax technical solutions do not work for organizational problems. You need to enforce code review and reject code that not using proper tags, otherwise devs will find a shortcut anyway.

Comment: If you want to make declaring these arguments as easy as possible, just write a macro so your devs can do `ARG(EmployeeID, int);`.

Comment: @Slava I disagree in that the existence of constructs like the const keyword suggest value in limiting scope for abuse. An organization can state an idea like "don't fall from this balcony" broadly, but better than that would be to place in a railing. Regardless, I'm not management and my scope for correcting organizational solution is less than my scope for writing bulletproof API's.